# FFMPEG - 4K HDR - MPEG - BIG FILE convert

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, video-streaming, html5-video, converters

I would like to ask how through ffmpeg to achieve the smallest file size and yet keep the best quality [LIKE Youtube convert].

Currently used:

```
ffmpeg -i "/home/sampe_4K_HDR.mkv" -map 0:00 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 66718k -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -x264-params "colorprim=bt2020:transfer=smpte2084:colormatrix=bt2020nc" -crf 18 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 "/home/sampe_4K_HDR.mp4"
```

But the size of the video after conversion is very large, I would like to preserve as much as possible the quality of the original video and get the smallest possible video size.

**Could you please advise? Write some examples of how to get better with smaller sizes? Thank you in advance and I apologize for my English in advance.**

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefore this is not a topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I do not ask for a programming question but how to achieve better settings for a smaller file.

Comment: “Quality and size” are the opposite things, you get one by sacrificeing the other. You are  setting the bitrate to 67 megabits per second, and using the worst possible preset. You should look up what those values do so you can find options that work better for you.

Comment: You're using both `-b:v` and `-crf`. These are two different *rate control* methods and are mutually exclusive. This means you can only use one, but not both, so one of them is being ignored.

Comment: Oh so only -b:v ?

Comment: There are several things you can do to keep better quality at the same bitrate (involves minor preprocessing), but try this question at https://video.stackexchange.com/ instead.